# PHP static Property Misbehaving in child classes

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to learn Object Oriented PHP and for this I tried to make login/logout system. The problem I am stuck in, is as given below:

**Scenario**: DB_CONNECT is Parent class and has static property array also Parent class has two child classes i.e. crud.php and user.php. crud.php adds data to parent's static array (see function login() in crud.php for more clarification) while user.php accesses/retrieves the data from that static array.

**Issue**: Child_2 gets empty array (since it is static array).

**Note1**: I have verified that data is being added by child_1. When accessed the static property via child_1 it shows data but empty via chiild_2!

**Note2**:parent class is DB_CONNECT child_1 class is crud.php and child_2 class is user.php

DB_CONNECT.php    (parent class)

```
class DB_CONNECT 
{
    /**
    * Stores a database object
    *
    * @var object A database object
    */
    protected $dbc;
    public static $user_name  ;
    public static $fname  ;
    public static $lname  ;
    public static $email  ;
    public static $psword ;
    public static $user_details = array();
    /**
    * Checks for a DB object or creates one if one isn't found
    *
    * @param object $db A database object
    */
    protected function __construct($db=NULL)
    {

        if ( is_object($db) )
        {
            $this->dbc = $db;
            echo 'Connected to DB by child constructor object';
        }
        else
        {
        // Constants are defined in /sys/config/db-cred.inc.php
            $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
            try
            {
                $this->dbc = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                // echo 'Connected to DB via parent';

            }
            catch ( Exception $e )
            {
            // If the DB connection fails, output the error
                // die ( $e->getMessage() );
                printf("Connection Failed: %s", $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function getParentDetails()
    {
        echo DB_CONNECT::$user_details[0];
    }

}
```

crud.php  (child class)

```
class CRUD extends DB_CONNECT
{
    // inherits protected $dbc;
    function __construct($dbo=null)
    {
        parent::__construct($dbo);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $result = '';
        self::$user_details[] = $_POST['fname'];
        self::$user_details[] = $_POST['pwd'];

        if (!empty($_SERVER)) {

            $select = "SELECT first_name, password FROM member_credentials 
                    WHERE first_name = '$_POST[fname]' AND 
                    password = '$_POST[pwd]'";
            $stmt = $this->dbc->prepare($select);
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
           // var_dump($result);
            if (!is_array($result)) {
                Redirect::to(404);
            } else {
                DB_CONNECT::$user_name = $result[0];

                // session_start(); 
                Session::set('admin', DB_CONNECT::$user_name);
                Redirect::to('../admin.php');
            }



        }

    }


}
```

user.php  (child class)

```
class User extends DB_CONNECT
{

    // inherits protected $dbc;
    function __construct($dbo=null)
    {
        parent::__construct($dbo);
    }

    public function getUserName($name=null)
    {
        return DB_CONNECT::$user_name;
    }


    public function getUserDetails()
    {
        echo DB_CONNECT::$user_details[0];
    }


}
```

index.php (instantiating class objects)

```
$user = new User();

$user->getUserDetails();
```

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce the issue. Works fine. https://3v4l.org/iDDAV

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Actually all works fine when using pure php i.e. no mysql pdo object is instantiated. I cross-checked it, yesterday, by applying the same scenario in dummy project and all works fine but in case of pdo, somehow it doesn't.  may be i am invoking two different pdos, that's why... do you think my suspect is correct?

Comment: I don't think PDO plays a role in this. The problem is more how you are trying to accomplish it. PS: `$_SERVER` is **never** empty.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I am trying this:-  you jump on login page. after you put your user credentials i.e. username, password and in case user credentials are matched with those stored in database  you are taken to admin page. Now as soon as the login is successful, those entered credentials are stored in static array of parent class. Then from admin page I use the user.php object to access that static array to retrieve data that was previously entered. Now this is the point where it is stuck.